# Cómo deshabilitar el evento click fuera del polygon en google maps?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

En este momento puedo clickear en cualquier parte del mapa, la idea es que se pueda clickear solamente donde esta el polígono. Gracias!

Controller:

```
    $scope.map = {

       events: {
                    click: function (mapModel, eventName, originalEventArgs) {

                        console.log("user defined event: " + eventName, mapModel, originalEventArgs);
                        var e = originalEventArgs[0];
                        $scope.$apply();
                        $scope.latitud = e.latLng.lat();
                        $scope.longitud = e.latLng.lng();
                    }
                }
            };

            $scope.polygons = [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    clickable: false,
                    path: [
                        {
                            latitude: -34.611345,
                            longitude: -55.450871
                        },
                        {
                            latitude: -34.594056,
                            longitude: -55.349145
                        },
                        {
                            latitude: -34.555720,
                            longitude: -55.327829
                        },
                        {
                            latitude: -34.475802,
                            longitude: -55.181059
                        },
                        {
                            latitude: -34.357981,
                            longitude: -54.867948
                        },
                        {
                            latitude: -34.038130,
                            longitude: 

-54.725110
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.013307,
                        longitude: -54.594584
                    },
                    //norte

                    {
                        latitude: -33.890545,
                        longitude: -54.510057
                    },
                    //

                    {
                        latitude: -34.008967,
                        longitude: -54.466028
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.803462,
                        longitude: -54.532865
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.852526,
                        longitude: -54.630319
                    },
                    //sur
                    {
                        latitude: -34.977426,
                        longitude: -54.953992
                    },


                    {
                        latitude: -34.918299,
                        longitude: -55.048001
                    },
                    //

                    {
                        latitude: -34.907468,
                        longitude: -55.263573
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.798692,
                        longitude: -55.393695
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.726899,
                        longitude: -55.457069
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.617944,
                        longitude: -55.488490
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.596882,
                        longitude: -55.465612
                    },
                    {
                        latitude: -34.611345,
                        longitude: -55.450871
                    },
                ],
                stroke: {
                    color: '#6060FB',
                    weight: 1

                },
                editable: true,
                draggable: false,
                geodesic: false,
                visible: true,
                fill: {
                    color: '#dbf7c8',
                    opacity: 0.1
                }
            }
        ];







HTML:
```

```html
 <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events='map.events'>
                                <ui-gmap-polygon static="true" clickable="p.clickable"  ng-repeat="p in polygons track by p.id" path="p.path" stroke="p.stroke" visible="p.visible"
                                                 geodesic="p.geodesic" fill="p.fill" fit="false" editable="p.editable" draggable="p.draggable"></ui-gmap-polygon>
                            </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu código no veo ninguna referencia al objeto `map`. Si sabes cómo obtenerla, entonces tienes que usar las opciones 
`scrollwheel`, `disableDoubleClickZoom` y `clickableIcons` y `draggable` para deshabilitar las interacciones con mouse. Esto no es igual a deshabilitar por completo los clicks en el mapa, pero ofrece un resultado similar.

```
map.setOptions({
  clickableIcons:false,
  scrollwheel:false,
  disableDoubleClickZoom:true,
  draggable:false
});
```